# Mexican Train Dominoes. During opening moves, can the following players start their trains if player 1 has left a double domino open?

Tags: dominoes

**The event** On your first move, you start your train as a series of dominoes ending in a double domino that you leave "unsatisfied", even after having drawn from the domino pool.

**The question** Can the following players, who have not yet done so, start their own trains, therefore leaving the double domino "unsatisfied" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most of your games, it would be fine for other players also to start their train while you finish yours.

During each player's first turn, they cannot interact with other players' trains. The [rules state](https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/mexican-train-dominoes-rules.htm) that only on **Subsequent Turns** can you place your domino on Another player's train. You would just want to make sure that your 2nd turn isn't skipped.